# Sympy automatically create variables for Derivatives

Tags: python, sympy

So what i want to make is an error propagation calculator using `sympy` and creating partial derivatives of an expression. My main question is mainly how can I create out of a string expression like e.g. "d*x+x**v" the symbolic variables so I can use `sympy.diff(expr,Variables)`
I know I can parse the expression from string to a sympy expression by using `parse_expr("string")` but is there a way for me to create all the symbols from the `"String"` so that i can use them in the function for calculating differentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `free_symbols` property will tell you these symbols:

```
>>> sympify("d*x+x**v").free_symbols
{d, v, x}
```